# Overlapping HTML Cells

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm working on a project for a web programming class currently where we have to use HTML tables to display a board from a game. I'm currently working on a game where you have a 2D array of cards where when you put them on your board they start to stack. I am looking to have the cards overlap as you gain them but am running into a few issues.

This is a mockup of what I'm working on theoretically right now,
https://jsfiddle.net/tokyo0709/dewcub0t/

For whatever reason right now I am having some layout anomalies particularly on the second row that I can't figure out, thought it was just the padding but that wasn't necessarily true. Also I'm currently overlapping by using individual ids for each row but that seems a bit cumbersome and that there should be a better option with classes.

This is a mockup of my desired layout,
[image: Overlapping Card Table]

HTML:

```
<body>
    <table>
        <tr id="rowOne">
            <td>
                <img src="https://picoolio.net/images/2015/11/08/overlappingTableImageTest122978.png">
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="https://picoolio.net/images/2015/11/08/overlappingTableImageTest2cf70f.png">
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="https://picoolio.net/images/2015/11/08/overlappingTableImageTest380241.png">
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <img src="https://picoolio.net/images/2015/11/08/overlappingTableImageTest58bc24.png">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="overlapOne">
            <td>
                <img src="https://picoolio.net/images/2015/11/08/overlappingTableImageTest122978.png">
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <img src="https://picoolio.net/images/2015/11/08/overlappingTableImageTest380241.png">
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="overlapTwo">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <img src="https://picoolio.net/images/2015/11/08/overlappingTableImageTest380241.png">
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
img {
    border: 2px solid black;
}
table {
    /* empty-cells: show; */
    position: relative;
}
td {
    padding: 0;
    height: 224px;
    width: 168px;
}
#overlapOne {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
}
#overlapTwo {
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: You really wants to use tables for these type of layouts? Why don't you use divs with CSS tables or normal layout? BTW I am still not sure where your issue lies. Can you create a mockup of the desired output please?

Comment: I've been told by others a table is not the way to go with this which I am understanding better now but in this case I'm required by my professor is requiring that we use a table.

Comment: So the problem occurs when the width of the browser is reduced, the blue column blocks shift away.

Comment: Hm yeah I am just noticing that, is that an issue with my positioning? Also any ideas on how to change my overlaps to classes instead of ids?

Comment: Replace `#` with `.` for replacing ids with classes in CSS. Similarly the id attribute needs to be changed to class in HTML. To solve the position change, delete the extra two tds in the both the overlaps https://jsfiddle.net/dewcub0t/1/

Comment: The issue with that is that, I did try that but unfortunately making the overlaps a class doesn't allow me to stack them evenly.

Comment: Using a table is definitely the wrong approach here, since table cells **cannot overlap**, they do not accept `overflow`, and you also cannot position stuff absolutely inside a table-cell. Content cannot overlap its containing cell either. This is true for css tables as well.